# How to specify a BaseSettings Config's env_file based on a field from the same class?

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to implement this logic

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings    

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ENVIRONMENT: str = 'local'
    SECRET_KEY: str = 'somekey'
    
    class Config:
        env_file = ".env.development" if Settings.ENVIRONMENT == "development" else ".env.local"
```

But I have an error:

```
NameError: name 'Settings' is not defined
```

I was trying `self.ENVIRONMENT` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings.ENVIRONMENT` doesn't work because the `Settings` class isn't defined yet by the time it's referenced in the `Config` definition. And `self.ENVIRONMENT` doesn't work because `self` here would refer to the `Config` class, and not the `Settings` class, which as mentioned, isn't fully defined yet, let alone has loaded the value for `ENVIRONMENT` yet.

This design has a sort of circular dependency because the `Settings` object needs to be initialized first (from direct `__init__` or environment variables or env files) to set an `ENVIRONMENT` value, ... but in order for Pydantic to initialize that class, it *already* needs to know which `env_file` to read to get the field values, ... but the `env_file` is determined by the `ENVIRONMENT` value, ... and so on.

The simple alternative would be to separate them into 2 `BaseSettings` classes instead:

```
class EnvConfig(BaseSettings):
    ENVIRONMENT: str = "local"

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    SECRET_KEY: str = "somekey"
```

Then create an instance of `EnvConfig` *first*, then reference that instance in defining `Settings`' `Config.env_file`:

```
class EnvConfig(BaseSettings):
    ENVIRONMENT: str = "local"

env_config = EnvConfig()

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    SECRET_KEY: str = "somekey"

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env.development" if env_config.ENVIRONMENT == "development" else ".env.local"
```

```
$ cat .env.local
SECRET_KEY=localkey
$ ENVIRONMENT=local python test.py
SECRET_KEY='localkey'

$ cat .env.development
SECRET_KEY=developmentkey
$ ENVIRONMENT=development python test.py
SECRET_KEY='developmentkey'
```